# What approach should I use to count the number pipes using these images?

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, image-recognition

I want to count the total number of pipes, i.e circular shapes in the following [Images](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1iw2W7dUg3ICGRt3hxOynUJCf-KQj2Pka?usp=sharing).
I tried Hough and canny methods, where I didn't even get 50% accuracy. Should I use ML for the same? Or what approach should I go for? I also want to label the count on each pipe.
Thank you

Comment: Can you add your code plus an exemplary image where hough transform did not perform as well as you thought?

Comment: As often, these are preprocessed images, which possibly loses valuable information. Please post the originals.